# Angular 7 - Auth0 - parseHash response null

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication, auth0

Auth0 issue.

My application is re-triggering the login event after sign-out on browser refresh and having issues with user profile. I tracked it down to parseHash in the authentication service:

```
  this.auth0.parseHash({ hash: window.location.hash }, (err, authResult) => {
  ...
  }
```

which is fired with the ngrx effect:

```
  @Effect()
  init$ = defer(() => {
    const userData = localStorage.getItem("user");

    if (userData != null && userData != 'undefined') {
       let authActionObservable = of(new Login({user: JSON.parse(userData)}));
       this.authService.handleAuthentication();
       return authActionObservable;
    }
    this.authService.handleAuthentication();
  });
```

It seems this.auth0.parseHash is returning null for both authResult and err after page refresh but on initial login authResult is populated correctly.

Technically the login is successful and I get the tokens. I checked the whole configuration, domain etc and everything seems fine. I also tried playing around with { hash: window.location.hash }.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the fact the state of the in-memory variables containing the tokens on the service was reset on each page refresh. Once I re-initialized the values in the constructor of the service, the issue went away.

Here example with localStorage for what I mean:

```
  constructor(public router: Router, private store: Store<State>, private http: HttpClient) {
    this._idToken = localStorage.getItem("Auth0IdToken");
    this._accessToken = localStorage.getItem("Auth0AccessToken");
    this._expiresAt = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("Auth0ExpiresAt"));
  }
```

Comment: You've shown how to persist the data across refreshes, but you don't show what to do with the persisted values. What do you do with these values?

Answer (score 1):

Often times I've seen HAR files get captured to help narrow down exactly what is happening during the logout workflow. Without seeing that exactly there are a couple things I could suggest taking a look at.

1. Review the [Logout Documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/logout)
2. Check out this Doc on [how to handle Redirects after logout](https://auth0.com/docs/logout/guides/redirect-users-after-logout) and evaluate how you are handling logouts.
3. You need to make sure you are passing the client_id parameter to the logout endpoint along with setting the Allowed Logout URL at the client level.

Now I could be wrong at the core of what's going on here but off the cuff that's a good fundamental place to start. Thanks!